# ANTLR4: Code generation for if statement

Tags: if-statement, compiler-construction, code-generation, antlr, antlr4

How do I emit branching code for an "if" statement defined like this in ANTLR4?

```
statement
    : // stuff
    | If LPar cond=expression RPar trueBlock=statement (Else falseBlock=statement)? # IfStatement
    ;
```

Basically, it's just like in the [Java.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4) example I used as a reference (see "statement" and "expression" rules).

The problem is that I can't figure out how to emit branching code for that in a listener and I'm trying to avoid adding any {code} in the grammar file. For example, if I `EnterIfStatement`, then it's too early to emit branching because the condition code is yet to be generated. And when I `ExitIfStatement`, it's too late because the whole if block code has already been created. ANTLR4 doesn't create any `EnterTrueBlock` event or something like that.

I think of a couple of possible workarounds using dictionaries to remember contexts and generate jump instructions when I catch related expressions but it just doesn't feel natural.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I learned the visitor pattern fits compilation tasks better.

```
public override string VisitIfStatement(MylangParser.IfStatementContext context)
{
    var hash = context.GetHashCode();
    Visit(context.cond);
    var elseLabel = "else" + hash;
    var endIfLabel = "end_if" + hash;
    emitter.Emit(OpCode.Jiz, elseLabel);
    if (context.trueBlock != null)
    {
        Visit(context.trueBlock);
    }
    emitter.Emit(OpCode.Jmp, endIfLabel);
    emitter.Mark(elseLabel);
    if (context.falseBlock != null)
    {
        Visit(context.falseBlock);
    }
    emitter.Mark(endIfLabel);
    return null;
}
```